# can I still upgrade ubuntu16.04 - GUI and terminal upgrade fails

Tags: upgrade, updates

I am unable to upgrade 16.04LTS. GUI upgrade does nothing at all but Terminal commands are fine until this step:

$ sudo do-release-upgrade

"Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading".

Have updated and tried this several times without success.
I know it is now past the EOL date but is there a way to still upgrade to the next LTS version?

Found a hold which I have removed with ( sudo apt-mark unhold ) but  (apt update) may show issues. here is a link to the results:   https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/4Q66ct6tFN/

Comment: Yes you should be able to upgrade, and your question is not off-topic as you're trying to move to a supported release, which is on-topic.   Make sure you have fully upgraded (ie. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`) and if no packages are present, check you don' t have any holds on packages (stopping an upgrade; `apt-mark showhold`).   If you don't find anything, I'd `sudo apt-get update` & read the messages looking for missing lines or issues there next.

Comment: @guiverc,  Thanks, It is fully upgraded with 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, etc. But (apt-mark showhold) gives GRAMPS. I've checked Synaptic for any problems with this package but nothing is reported. So what do I do about this hold - uninstall Gramps?
I also ran (sudo apt-get update) again and it gives a list of 15 Hits and 5 Get all showing 'InRelease' but none of the urls shown can be found. I do not know what this telling me, if I send the list can you advise please?

Comment: If you have a hold; then someone on your box with `sudo` access has placed the hold. You remove it (`apt-mark unhold`). For us to see the `apt update` issues, yes you'll need to provide a link via your question (extra detail should be added to your question & not provided via comment).

Comment: Yes I do see issues, I see a *bionic* source for a *xenial* system?  plus a number of 3rd party sources (which can create issues as they are not built to *release-upgrade* but only work on the system they were built for).  For best results you should remove 3rd party packages (`ppa-purge`) and once back to only official packages you may have a reasonable shot, however the 3rd party *bionic* source is a potentially huge problem (if it contained packages with higher package-versions than *bionic* so it'll replace official *bionic* packages as 3rd party packages commonly do...)